# Select-string by storing the pattern in a variable. (so that the pattern can be changed dynamically)

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to search a file and retrieve lines containing a particular phrase. I am trying the following code but it retrievs nothing. Variable $searchIP has nothing in it.

```
$pattern = "query for " + $customer_Id
$pattern = $pattern.ToString()
$searchIP =  Select-String -Encoding UNICODE -Path .\test_file.log -Pattern $pattern
```

The pattern I match changes with the customer id and so I cannot hard code it. I was trying to search the file with a variable ($pattern) that contains the string I need to search.

So that every time the customer ID gets updated, I would receive the lines containing the updated customer_ID.

This works fine but I cannot change the customer_ID dynamically.

```
$searchIP =  Select-String -Encoding UNICODE -Path .\test_file.log -Pattern "query for 101231019"
```

I have tried this but it gives an error.

```
Select-String -Encoding UNICODE -Path .\test_file.log -Pattern "query for " + $customer_Id
```

Where am I going wrong? Is it possible to Select-String using a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the first two lines to this:

```
$pattern = "query for $customer_Id"
```

And then your last line would just be:

```
Select-String -Encoding UNICODE -Path .\test_file.log -Pattern $pattern
```

Comment: It works , thankyou. But it was really strange. I have opened two tabs in Powershell ISE. The code works completely fine in one and dosent work in the other!!